# Compile Error: Method or Data Member Not Found vba

Tags: vba, excel, methods

I am trying to automate the cleaning of a worksheet template to create a flat file for database insertion.

Below is my code that's throwing the error. I am trying to unfreeze panes for the worksheet but keep getting the Compile Error: Method or Data Member not found error on that line.

wsPerm is the worksheet I am working on.

```
'Unhide All Columns
wsPerm.Unprotect Password:="DRP"
wsPerm.Range("A1:FB1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
wsPerm.FreezePanes = False
wsPerm.Activate
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
wsPerm.Cells.UnMerge
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.FreezePanes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841228.aspx) property only works on the [`Window`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835196.aspx) object type so in your case, remove

```
wsPerm.FreezePanes = False
```

Which leaves:

```
'Unhide All Columns
wsPerm.Unprotect Password:="DRP"
wsPerm.Range("A1:FB1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
wsPerm.Activate
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
wsPerm.Cells.UnMerge
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I thought I tried both methods I didn't realize when I was trying ActiveWindow, I forgot to delete wsPerm.FreezePanes! thank you!!